# Opt+arrow cursor manipulation stopped working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Part of my regular repertoire of keyboard shortcuts is <kbd>Opt</kbd>+`arrow` and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+`arrow` for moving (and selecting) a word at a time in apps like Word, TextEdit, etc.

A couple days ago <kbd>Opt</kbd>+`arrow` stopped working in most places (though not all). I figured a reboot would clear it out but it did not. The only place I can find that it works right now, strangely enough, is a textbox on a website in Chrome. So I can use it this dialog I'm typing in right now, but not the URL field of the browser.

Any idea how to fix and/or reset this behavior? I'm lost without it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

Even though it wasn't selected, I did have installed "Unicode Hex Input" as an Input Soure (along side U.S) in the Keyboard->Input Sources preference pane. I removed the Unicode option altogether, and the opt-arrow shortcut started working again instantly.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me find the solution for OS X 10.6/Snow Leopard, which is a little different. The **Input Sources** tab is under **System Preferences->Language & Text**, instead of **Keyboard**. I had **Unicode Hex Input** installed and enabled; unchecking it fixed the Option-Arrow problem, and *re-checking it again* doesn't seem to bring the problem back! Very strange. I'll probably leave it unchecked just in case.

Edit: More details. It looks like the actual problem has to do with the **Keyboard & Character Viewer** item in the menu bar. (This appears as a national flag when nation-specific input is selected, or a yellow-on-purple "U+" when Unicode Hex Input is selected.) When **Unicode Hex Input** is selected in the Keyboard & Character Viewer, the Option-Arrow keys don't work in some apps. You can leave Unicode installed and enabled in **Language & Text->Input Sources**, but it can't be selected in the Keyboard & Character Viewer.